# App crashes when registration button is pressed

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm  a bit new to android studio and java but not to programming. I am developing an app similar to Uber.

When i first wrote the login and registration activity code everything went smoothly. Now after completing most of the functionalities of the app the resignation method crashes the app. I have literally tried everything, including getting a new JSON file.

Any help will be greatly appreciate.

[image]

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;


public class CustomerLoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private EditText mEmail, mPassword;
private Button mLogin, mRegistration;

private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_customer_login);

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    mAuthListener =[enter image description here][1] new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            //store info of current user
            FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
            if(user!=null){
                Intent intent = new Intent(CustomerLoginActivity.this, CustomerMapActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }

        }
    };

    mEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
    mPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);

    mLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);
    mRegistration = (Button) findViewById(R.id.registration);

    mRegistration.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String email = mEmail.getText().toString();
            String password = mPassword.getText().toString();
            mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(CustomerLoginActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if(!task.isSuccessful()){
                        Toast.makeText(CustomerLoginActivity.this, "sign up error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }else{
                        String user_id = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
                        DatabaseReference current_user_db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child("Customers").child(user_id);
                        current_user_db.setValue(true);

                    }

                }
            });
        }
    });

    mLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String email = mEmail.getText().toString();
            String password = mPassword.getText().toString();
            mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(CustomerLoginActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if(!task.isSuccessful()){
                        Toast.makeText(CustomerLoginActivity.this, "sign in error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                }
            });

        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    mAuth.removeAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
}
}
```

Comment: What is the crash logs. Show the crash logs!?

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39842599/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-given-string-is-empty-or-null-when-executing

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/a6ouh.png @Xenolion

Comment: Check the answer below by @jignesh the problem is your edit text do not have any value so they are empty you can confirm this by filling them before click the registration button!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

email and password should not be null or empty

```
String email = mEmail.getText().toString();
String password = mPassword.getText().toString();

if(email.isEmpty() || password.isEmpty())
    return;    //you need to display message to the user

mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
.addOnCompleteListener(CustomerLoginActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() 
{ 
    ...
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Need to validate emails and password must not be null

```
  String email = mEmail.getText().toString();
                    String password = mPassword.getText().toString();
                    if(password.length()==0 || email.length()==0)
                    {
                    // enter the email and password 
                    return;
                    }

                   mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(CustomerLoginActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if(!task.isSuccessful()){
                        Toast.makeText(CustomerLoginActivity.this, "sign up error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }else{
                        String user_id = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
                        DatabaseReference current_user_db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child("Customers").child(user_id);
                        current_user_db.setValue(true);

                    }

                }
            });
```

Comment: The login method works perfectly.... Its the Registration method that crashes the app... Do you still recommend that I alter the Login method? @jignesh

Comment: Thanks a lot mate!... much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

String email = mEmail.getText().toString();

String password = mPassword.getText().toString();

/*Kindly check for null as we can't have it */

if(email.isEmpty() || password.isEmpty())
   return;

/*

Your code

*/