# App crashes during login when fields are empty

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have this login screen where I enter a username and a password to log into the firebase. When I enter the fields correctly (valid username and pass) it works as it should, however, when I press "login" and the fields are incorrect or empty, the app simply crashes.

I keep getting the following error: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Given String is empty or null`.

I have tried using error handling for when the given values are empty/null as well, but no results. I also checked StackOverflow for that particular error and got that the "API key was the problem", which is not a valid solution to this problem.

My code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

private TextInputLayout userNameInputLayout;
private TextInputLayout userPasswordInputLayout;
private TextInputEditText userName;
private TextInputEditText userPassword;
private Button button;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    userNameInputLayout = findViewById(R.id.userNameInputLayout);
    userPasswordInputLayout = findViewById(R.id.userPasswordInputLayout);
    userName = findViewById(R.id.userName);
    userPassword = findViewById(R.id.userPassword);
    button = findViewById(R.id.button);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        final String email = userNameInputLayout.getEditText().getText().toString().toLowerCase().trim() + "@companyaddress.com";
        final String password = userPasswordInputLayout.getEditText().getText().toString().toLowerCase().trim();



mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
            updateUI(user);

            String uid = user.getUid();
            DocumentReference userRef = db.document("users/" + uid);


            userRef.get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
                    final String permission = documentSnapshot.getString("permission");

                    if (permission.equals("user")) {
                        Intent sendMessage = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), userMainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(sendMessage);
                    } else {
                        Intent sendMessage2 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), adminMainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(sendMessage2);

                    }
                }
            });


        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wrong username or password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        }
    }
});

        }
    });

}
```

Part of the XML file for username input:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/userNameInputLayout"
android:focusable="false" android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
android:backgroundTint="#2D77B6"
android:textColorHint="#3281C5"
android:textColor="#2D77B6"
app:errorEnabled="true">

<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
    android:hint="Username"
    android:textColorHint="#3281C5"
    android:textColor="#2D77B6"
    android:backgroundTint="#2D77B6"
    android:inputType="text" />
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: Does the Toast you created for telling the user that the password is wrong ever show?

Comment: No. The app crashes right when the mAuth.signIn method is run, so it never gets that far.

Comment: Apparently, getting a new google-services.json file and uploading that into the projects files to update it could fix the problem, as stated in this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/40212694/12647189

Comment: If I understood it correctly, that was only if your current key was null? Which it isn't in my case.

Comment: May I ask why you are trimming and adding '@companyaddress' onto the end of each email before it is sent to firebase?

Comment: I use firebase/firestore to login via email, and wanted to make so they only need the username to login, and just add the company email afterwards.

Comment: Try printing the result of the email variable after it's done all of that. I think you are concatenating wrongly.

Comment: Also, not too sure on the Java Android development as I haven't done it in a while, but it seems you have add an `onClickListener` to your button to get the two fields and then call the `mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword` without passing any parameters to the function, so you're running the function with no email or password passed into it? Maybe take the `mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword` method out of the listener and make a new method with the email and password parameters as parameters to login

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your current code, when the user presses the login button, the code gets the two fields and stores it in the two variables (email and password) and in the same `onClickListener` you also call the `signInWithEmailAndPassword` Firebase function, that takes in two strings (email and password) yet the provided values might not have been assigned.

Change this part of the code:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    final String email = userNameInputLayout.getEditText().getText().toString().toLowerCase().trim() + "@companyaddress.com";
    final String password = userPasswordInputLayout.getEditText().getText().toString().toLowerCase().trim();



mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(new 
OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
@Override
public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
        FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        updateUI(user);

        String uid = user.getUid();
        DocumentReference userRef = db.document("users/" + uid);


        userRef.get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
                final String permission = documentSnapshot.getString("permission");

                if (permission.equals("user")) {
                    Intent sendMessage = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), userMainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(sendMessage);
                } else {
                    Intent sendMessage2 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), adminMainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(sendMessage2);

                }
            }
        });


    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wrong username or password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    }
}
});

    }
});
```

To this:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    final String email = userNameInputLayout.getEditText().getText().toString().toLowerCase().trim() + "@companyaddress.com";
    final String password = userPasswordInputLayout.getEditText().getText().toString().toLowerCase().trim();
    loginWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
}

private void loginWithEmailAndPassword(email, password){

mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(new 
OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
@Override
public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
        FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        updateUI(user);

        String uid = user.getUid();
        DocumentReference userRef = db.document("users/" + uid);


        userRef.get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
                final String permission = documentSnapshot.getString("permission");

                if (permission.equals("user")) {
                    Intent sendMessage = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), userMainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(sendMessage);
                } else {
                    Intent sendMessage2 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), adminMainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(sendMessage2);

                }
            }
        });


    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wrong username or password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    }
}
});

    }
});
```

Comment: @RobinSvensson Let me get up my Android studio and try it on my end for you. Can't see why that wouldn't work.

Comment: I didn't have time to try this more until today, but after I made some error handling, your solution did work. Thank you!

Comment: @RobinSvensson No problem, glad you solved it as I could not start Android studio for some reason?