# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Given String is empty or null

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

i am making login page so i have connected this app with firebase database there is email and password in database so i am trying to
Signinwithemailandpassword     but it doesn't work whenever i try to run the apps it crashes

loginpage.java

```
public class loginpage extends AppCompatActivity {
    ActivityLoginpageBinding binding;
    Button loginbtn;
    TextView login;
    FirebaseAuth auth;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        binding = ActivityLoginpageBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_loginpage);
        login=findViewById(R.id.login);
        auth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        loginbtn=findViewById(R.id.loginbtn);

        loginbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            final  String email=binding.email.getText().toString();
           final  String password=binding.pwd.getText().toString();
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(binding.email.getText().toString(),binding.pwd.getText().toString()).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if(task.isSuccessful()){
                            Intent intent=new Intent(loginpage.this,MainActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            Toast.makeText(loginpage.this, "successfull", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        else{
                            Toast.makeText(loginpage.this, "failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Log.d("MyTag", task.getException().getMessage());
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent=new Intent(loginpage.this,signup.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

loginpage.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".loginpage">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView14"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:text="Instagram"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="242dp"
        android:layout_height="235dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.497"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView14"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/instagram" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView16"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Welcome to social world"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView3" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/email"
        android:layout_width="297dp"
        android:layout_height="49dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
        android:background="@drawable/inputbg"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Email"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.491"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView16" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/pwd"
        android:layout_width="297dp"
        android:layout_height="49dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/inputbg"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.491"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/email"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.017" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/loginbtn"
        android:layout_width="298dp"
        android:layout_height="51dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
        android:text="login"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.495"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/pwd" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView15"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Don't have a account? "
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/login"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/loginbtn"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.859" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/login"
        android:layout_width="63dp"
        android:layout_height="18dp"
        android:text="Sign up!"
        android:textColor="#F10606"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView15"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/loginbtn"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.86" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>`
```

Error

```
12/24 12:13:07: Launching 'app' on Pixel 5 API 26.
App restart successful without requiring a re-install.
$ adb shell am start -n "com.example.instagram/com.example.instagram.signup" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Connected to process 28962 on device 'Pixel_5_API_26 [emulator-5554]'.
Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page.
I/zygote: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
W/zygote: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
I/FirebaseApp: Device unlocked: initializing all Firebase APIs for app [DEFAULT]
W/zygote: Skipping duplicate class check due to unrecognized classloader
I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.measurement.dynamite:86 and remote module com.google.android.gms.measurement.dynamite:15
I/DynamiteModule: Selected local version of com.google.android.gms.measurement.dynamite
D/FirebaseAuth: Notifying id token listeners about user ( xmoP2dPpYhUD9acalVCdTqBiJ7e2 ).
I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization successful
I/zygote: Background concurrent copying GC freed 5896(1215KB) AllocSpace objects, 2(40KB) LOS objects, 62% free, 910KB/2MB, paused 1.368ms total 117.164ms
V/FA: onActivityCreated
V/FA: App measurement collection enabled
V/FA: App measurement enabled for app package, google app id: com.example.instagram, 1:582042892352:android:f97df8209dee5aa33f87a5
I/FA: App measurement initialized, version: 74029
I/FA: To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
I/FA: To enable faster debug mode event logging run:
      adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app com.example.instagram
D/FA: Debug-level message logging enabled
D/FA: Resetting session stitching token to not null
I/zygote: NativeAllocBackground concurrent copying GC freed 4528(591KB) AllocSpace objects, 7(140KB) LOS objects, 59% free, 1046KB/2MB, paused 3.590ms total 105.851ms
V/FA: Connecting to remote service
V/FA: Detected application was in foreground
V/FA: Session started, time: 37468155
I/zygote: Do partial code cache collection, code=30KB, data=30KB
V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
I/zygote: After code cache collection, code=24KB, data=28KB
I/zygote: Increasing code cache capacity to 128KB
I/FA: Tag Manager is not found and thus will not be used
I/zygote: Do partial code cache collection, code=24KB, data=46KB
I/zygote: After code cache collection, code=24KB, data=46KB
I/zygote: Increasing code cache capacity to 256KB
I/zygote: JIT allocated 71KB for compiled code of void android.widget.TextView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int)
I/zygote: Compiler allocated 4MB to compile void android.widget.TextView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int)
D/OpenGLRenderer: HWUI GL Pipeline
V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
I/chatty: uid=10097(u0_a97) Measurement Wor identical 1 line
V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 37468263
V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
D/: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x9f3f98c0, tid 29000
I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0x9f4d4620: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9f4d4620: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x9f6ff450)
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9f4d4620: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x9f6ff450)
I/Choreographer: Skipped 51 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
D/FA: Connected to remote service
V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 7
W/View: dispatchProvideAutofillStructure(): not laid out, ignoring
I/AssistStructure: Flattened final assist data: 3448 bytes, containing 1 windows, 12 views
I/zygote: Do full code cache collection, code=124KB, data=61KB
I/zygote: After code cache collection, code=120KB, data=46KB
V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
I/zygote: Do partial code cache collection, code=122KB, data=50KB
I/zygote: After code cache collection, code=122KB, data=50KB
I/zygote: Increasing code cache capacity to 512KB
V/FA: Recording user engagement, ms: 54118
V/FA: onActivityCreated
V/FA: Connecting to remote service
V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
V/FA: Activity paused, time: 37522383
V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 37522548
V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9f4d4620: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x9f6ff450)
D/FA: Connected to remote service
V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 4
W/View: dispatchProvideAutofillStructure(): not laid out, ignoring
I/AssistStructure: Flattened final assist data: 2780 bytes, containing 1 windows, 10 views
I/zygote: Do full code cache collection, code=249KB, data=167KB
I/zygote: After code cache collection, code=249KB, data=134KB
V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
I/zygote: Do partial code cache collection, code=249KB, data=139KB
I/zygote: After code cache collection, code=249KB, data=139KB
I/zygote: Increasing code cache capacity to 1024KB
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.instagram, PID: 28962
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Given String is empty or null
        at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.Preconditions.checkNotEmpty(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@18.1.0:2)
        at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@21.1.0:1)
        at com.example.instagram.loginpage$1.onClick(loginpage.java:44)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6256)
        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1219)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24701)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

need to find out the mistake and why app crashes

Comment: is your **current_key** is valid? in to **google-services.json**

Comment: sorry ?? i couldn't get you

Comment: i think it will help to you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39842599/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-given-string-is-empty-or-null-when-executing

Comment: "doesn't work" doesn't provide enough information so we can help. What exactly doesn't work? Do you have any errors? Please respond using @AlexMamo

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Where have you set the values for the email and password when you are authenticating with firebase?
In your code, you are doing `binding.email.getText().toString()` and `binding.pwd.getText().toString()`. These are potentially empty as I am not seeing you set the value of those views either in your xml or in your code and hence the exception is being thrown.

Just try setting those in your xml or via code and try authentication, it should work.

Comment: i am getting email and password in xml through user and authenticate with the firebase        what should i do to fix that error in your view???please help out

Comment: the code that you have shared for xml, I do not see you setting the value for email and password. And in your code, you are just getting the reference of the views and passing the value stored in it (which is currently null/empty) in your click listener.

If the values are fixed, just add those in your edit text at xml level by using android:text attribute for both email/password just to see if it works.
But recommended way would be to take input from user in your code by adding the textChangedListeneres for both the email & pwd and then using those values while you authenticate.